# What is the meaning of executionRoleArn in boto3 API for EMR Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-emr

According to the API for the function [start_job_run](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr-serverless.html#EMRServerless.Client.start_job_run), I need to give a `executionRoleArn` - what is this? I thought is the name of the IAM role I created for it (the one I give the job as the runtime role when I try it from the AWS UI dashboard), but it doesn't work.

Comment: ExecutionRoleArn is the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the IAM role that will be used for the job run. This role should have the necessary permissions to access the input and output data and to run the job. @nirkov

Comment: @CoolNetworking
something like that - ```arn:aws:iam::9999999999:role/myRole``` instead of the role name - myRole?

Comment: yes, that is correct. @nirkov

Answer (score 0):

`executionRoleArn` is the ARN (Amazon Resource Name) for the role which you are using to interact with other services from within the job, it's not just the name but the full identifier and usually looks like the following:

`arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myrole`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr-serverless/latest/APIReference/API_StartJobRun.html#emrserverless-StartJobRun-request-executionRoleArn